# How to create SQL query with multiple JSON parameters in golang application?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

As you can see in my **Golang** application I have an array called `layers`.

```
type Details struct {
    Total int `json:"total"`
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
}

type Layer struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
    City string `json:"city"`
    Details []Details `json:"details"`
}

layers := []Layer{
    {
        ID: 107509018555,
        City: "London",
        Details: []Details{
            {
                Total: 158,
                Gender: "Male",
            },
            {
                Total: 689,
                Gender: "Female",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        ID: 108509018556,
        City: "New York",
        Details: []Details{
            {
                Total: 756,
                Gender: "Male",
            },
            {
                Total: 356,
                Gender: "Female",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I want to insert data of that array to the table of the **PostgreSQL** database. My question is how to create such SQL query in the application?

**QUERY**:

```
INSERT INTO layers (ID, CITY, DETAILS) VALUES
(107509018555, 'London', '[{"total":158,"gender":"Male"},{"total":689,"gender":"Female"}]'::json),
(108509018556, 'New York', '[{"total":756,"gender":"Male"},{"total":356,"gender":"Female"}]':json);
```

Comment: Why would you want it to be of type `json`? I find this data type to be problematic, to say the least. If you need a flexible schema, you might want to consider [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I cannot comment, I assume that:

1. You're using golang's [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) or similar package.
2. In your database, `details` column has type `JSONB`

A simple approach is to loop your slice `layers` and build query string to this:

```golang
"INSERT INTO layers (id,city,details) VALUES ($1,$2,$3), ($4,$5,$6)"
```

For `id` and `city`, you can pass the params easily, however you need to pass JSON bytes for `details`. Which means, you'll need to **marshal Details struct to JSON bytes for insert/update** and **unmarshal 'details' result to struct when SELECT**

You will need to:

1. Define new struct that encapsulates the slice of `Detail` (we'll call it `Details`) then the `Details` should implement these interfaces.
2. Implements [driver.Valuer](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface to convert `Details` to JSON byte slice that can be understood by the database
3. Implements [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface to unmarshal JSON byte slice from database to your struct

The code should look like this:

```golang
type Detail struct {
    Total  int    `json:"total"`
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
}

// this will implement driver.Valuer and sql.Scanner
type Details []Detail

// so that the database can understand your value, useful for INSERT/UPDATE
func (d Details) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(d)
}

// so that the database can convert db value to your struct, useful for SELECT
func (d *Details) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed for scanning Details")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &d)
}
```

The complete code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Layer struct {
    ID      int     `json:"id"`
    City    string  `json:"city"`
    Details Details `json:"details"`
}

// this will implement driver.Valuer and sql.Scanner
type Details []Detail

// so that the database can understand your value, useful for INSERT/UPDATE
func (d Details) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(d)
}

// so that the database can convert db value to your struct, useful for SELECT
func (d *Details) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed for scanning Details")
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(b, &d)
}

type Detail struct {
    Total  int    `json:"total"`
    Gender string `json:"gender"`
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:pass@host:port/db?sslmode=disable")
    exitIfError(err)

    query, params := prepareQuery([]Layer{
        {
            ID:      107509018555,
            City:    "London",
            Details: []Detail{{Total: 158, Gender: "Male"}, {Total: 689, Gender: "Female"}},
        },
        {
            ID:      108509018556,
            City:    "New York",
            Details: []Detail{{Total: 756, Gender: "Male"}, {Total: 356, Gender: "Female"}},
        },
    })

    log.Println(query) 
    // INSERT INTO layers (id, city, details) VALUES ($1, $2, $3),($4, $5, $6)
    log.Println(params) 
    // [107509018555 London [{158 Male} {689 Female}] 108509018556 New York [{756 Male} {356 Female}]]

    result, err := db.Exec(query, params...)
    exitIfError(err)


    rows, _ := result.RowsAffected()
    log.Println(rows) // 2 rows inserted
}

func exitIfError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func prepareQuery(layers []Layer) (string, []interface{}) {
    query := "INSERT INTO layers (id, city, details) VALUES "
    params := []interface{}{}
    x := 1

    for _, layer := range layers {
        query += fmt.Sprintf("($%d, $%d, $%d),", x, x+1, x+2)
        params = append(params, layer.ID, layer.City, layer.Details)
        x += 3
    }

    query = strings.TrimSuffix(query, ",")
    return query, params
}
```

Reference:

https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/using-postgresql-jsonb

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Sorry for the late answer. In my case, I decided to use your code with little changes. For example, I used `json.Marshal` to make the valid json from `[]Details`. Can I ask you one more question?! How to replace the last character of the string with another character? As I can see you use `query = strings.TrimSuffix(query, ",")`.

Comment: I use `strings.TrimSuffix` to remove the last `","` character that was added by `fmt.Sprintf("($%d, $%d, $%d),", x, x+1, x+2)`. If you want to change last character of string to "x" for example, you can do it by `str = str[:len(str)-1] + "x"`